# Get clusters of words using Kmeans and TF-IDF

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, tf-idf

I am trying to clusters text words.
Let suppose I have a list of text

```py
text=["WhatsApp extends 'confusing' update deadline",
"India begins world's biggest Covid vaccine drive",
"Nepali climbers make history with K2 winter summit"]
```

I implemented TF-IDF on this data

```py
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
feat = vec .fit_transform(text)
```

After that, I applied Kmeans

```py
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num).fit(feat)
```

The thing I am confused about is how I get clusters of words such as

```
cluster 0  
WhatsApp, update,biggest   
cluster 1  
history,biggest ,world's   
etc.
```

Comment: You list of strings is broke i guess. There are some ' and , missing. What is the result of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get_feature_names()` method from the [`TfidfVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) class with the predictions from [`KMeans`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) to inspect the words in each cluster.

Here's a minimal example with two clusters and the three sentence provided by you:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

text = ["WhatsApp extends 'confusing' update deadline",
        "India begins world's biggest Covid vaccine drive",
        "Nepali climbers make history with K2 winter summit"]

vec = TfidfVectorizer()
feat = vec.fit_transform(text)
kmeans = KMeans(2).fit(feat)
pred = kmeans.predict(feat)

for i in range(2):
    print(f"Cluster #{i}:")
    words = []
    for sentence in np.array(text)[pred==i]:
        words += [fn for fn in vec.get_feature_names() if fn in sentence]
    print(words)
```

Result:

```
Cluster #0:
['confusing', 'deadline', 'extends', 'update', 'begins', 'biggest', 'drive', 'vaccine', 'world']
Cluster #1:
['climbers', 'history', 'make', 'summit', 'winter', 'with']
```